# JSON Array parsing element by element

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON array like this:

```
[
   {
     "stats": {
     "callQuality": 5,
     "audioRecvRemoteMute": false,
     "audioRecvLocalMute": true,
     },
     "rtpStatsList": [
     {
        "media": 1,
        "direction": 1,
        "content": true,
     }
   ],
   "timestamp": 1460208299000
   },
   {
      "stats": {
      "callQuality": 5,
      "audioRecvRemoteMute": false,
      "audioRecvLocalMute": true,
   },
   "rtpStatsList": [
   {
      "media": 1,
      "direction": 1,
      "content": true,
   }
   ],
  "timestamp": 1460208299000
 },
]
```

There are multiple elements (180 elements for e.g.) in the array. I need "media" and "direction" parameters under rtpStatsList.
Any useful suggestion to parse the same using JAVA?

Comment: Many json parsing libraries exist.  Consider google.  maybe search for "json parser java".  Consider the first link you find; it will be on an unfamiliar site, but is probably good.  Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here Check this out

`String data = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse2.getEntity());`
`JSONArray js=new JSONArray(data)`
`for(int i=0;i<js.length();i++) {`

`JSONObject total = js.getJSONObject(js);{`
`JSONArray rtpStatsList=total.getJSONArray("rtpStatsList");`
 `for(int j=0;j<rtpStatsList.length();j++) {`

```
                     `JSONObject jsonObject = rtpStatsList.getJSONObject(j);` 
                      media = jsonObject.getString("media");
                      direction = jsonObject.getString("direction");                  
                      }
                      }`
```

Comment: Coded differently. But followed a similar approach

Answer (score 0):

Use this: http://theoryapp.com/parse-json-in-java/
You have an extensive explanation of:

- Build a URL.
- Read from the URL.
- Build a JSON object for the content.
- Retrieve the first result from an array of results.
- Print out the information.